# Open Tor-Browser

Tags: tor, tor-browser

I've installed the Tor-Browser ([following this instructions](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tor-browser-bundle-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/)) via command line. I'm now searching for the program using Ubuntu search but it doesn't show up.

I've also tried calling the browser via command line. How can I open it now that it's installed?

Comment: How did you install it? What instructions did you follow?

Comment: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tor-browser-bundle-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the username

```
$ cd ~/.tor-browser
$ ./start-tor-browser
```

Comment: No such file or directory